# Why does a pre-configured @FetchRequest not update the SwiftUI view?

Tags: swiftui, core-data, swiftui-list

Whenever I am using a pre-configured NSFetchRequest like so:

```
extension Note {
    static var requestPrivateDBNotesByDate: NSFetchRequest<Note> {
        let request = Note.fetchRequest()
        request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Note.createdDate, ascending: true)]
        request.affectedStores = [PersistenceController.shared.privatePersistentStore]
        return request
}
```

to do a @FetchRequest within a SwiftUI view:

```
@FetchRequest(fetchRequest: Note.requestPrivateDBNotesByDate)
private var notes: FetchedResults<Note>
```

the SwiftUI view is not updating when I add a Note entity to CoreData:

```
func addNote(name: String, context: NSManagedObjectContext) {
    context.perform {
        let note = Note(context: context)
        note.displayName = name
        note.createdDate = .now
        try? context.save()
    }
}
```

If I use a simple @FetchRequest within my SwiftUI view like so:

```
@FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [SortDescriptor(\.displayName, order: .forward)]
) private var notes: FetchedResults<Note>
```

the view updates whenever I add a now Note.

Why is the pre-configured @FetchRequest not updating my SwiftUI view?

Note: I can force a view update by adding `context.refresh(chat, mergeChanges: false)` after `context.save()` but then my question would be, why do I need to force a refresh with a pre-configured @FetchRequest while it is not necessary with a simple @FetchRequest.

Is the forced refresh the only/correct way to go?
Am I missing something?

**Update:**

This is how I get the privatePersistentStore for the affectedStores property in the pre-configured NSFetchRequest.

```
var privatePersistentStore: NSPersistentStore {
    var privateStore: NSPersistentStore?
    let descriptions = persistentContainer.persistentStoreDescriptions
    
    for description in descriptions {
        if description.cloudKitContainerOptions?.databaseScope == .private {
            guard let url = description.url else { fatalError("NO STORE URL!") }
            guard let store = persistentContainer.persistentStoreCoordinator.persistentStore(for: url) else { fatalError("NO STORE!") }
            privateStore = store
        }
    }
    guard let privateStore else { fatalError("NO PRIVATE STORE!") }
    return privateStore
}
```

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this, maybe it has something to do with `request.affectedStores = [PersistenceController.shared.privatePersistentStore]`

Comment: @JoakimDanielson You are right, if I comment out the affectedStores property in the NSFetchRequest the SwiftUI view updates correctly. That said, the affectedStores property is exactly the reason why I need the more configurable version of the NSFetchRequest.

Comment: Yes I can reproduce as well now if I assign my store to that property. Unfortunately I don't have any experience with using multiple stores so I can't really help. I guess this is some limitation or bug with the new FetchRequest type.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson In any case, thank you for your quick feedback!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you forgot to assign the new note to the store you are fetching from, e.g.

```
context.assign(to: PersistenceController.shared.privatePersistentStore)
try? context.save()
```

Comment: That works, thanks! context.refresh(note, mergeChanges: false) after save() no longer needed. But why is assign(to) needed? I have a private and a shared store (for NSPersistentCloudKitContainer zone sharing feature). Without the assign(to) new entities landed in the correct store so far, too. How did the system know? Was it pure luck on my side that it worked so far without assign(to)? And, why do SwiftUI view updates work without assign(to) when I use the SwiftUI Wrapper @FetchRequest (vs the preconfigured NSFetchRequest with the affectedStores prop set? Questions over questions! :-)

Comment: Yes it was pure luck. Another way to do this is to create configurations in the model editor and choose which entities are in each configuration and then load each store with a different configuration. That way when you fetch or save an entity that is only configured to be in one store you don't need to tell it which store cause it knows.

Comment: Configurations make sense, too. Thanks for the suggestion! But, still not completely convinced on the need for assign(to) or configurations: why is Apple using neither in its sample code with two stores (private and shared)? See here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/sharing_core_data_objects_between_icloud_users. (in file PersistenceController+Photo, method addPhoto).

Comment: Configurations are needed for cloud and local stores. Maybe aren’t needed for private and shared then.